# Animation in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, simulation, simulator

i'm creating a simulation model using Google maps, i have created a new KML layer and marked few areas which are dangerous to users to go through, now i want to add a moving object to resemble a person on top of it and give a warning when that object nearing the area, does any one have the idea of doing animation of that kind using Google maps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a moving marker i think you can use the setPosition of the [marker object](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) in a for loop feeding it with the coords of a line let's say.